# Flutter Design Layout - Layout Suggestions

Tags: flutter

I am completely new to flutter.  I have an app that I wrote with Android studio and now need to create it for IOS.  I was told that I would be better off to write the app in flutter so that way I would only have one code base to deal with instead of 2, 1 for android and the other for ios.  So I started with flutter dev site with the sample app to build layout for.  The first thing is says to do is Layout all the areas first.

Since I am trying to duplicate my app in flutter, I thought it was wise to walk through the tutorial, using my real world scenario instead of the fake one they provided.

After looking at the suggestion that was posted, I went about this a different way.  I found another informational site that doesn't code a layout but shows you how you breakdown a flutter layout.  I have provided this photo, and then I have provided a similar image, but using my Real World App.  I have not found any real good explanatory tutorials to help me understand how to create the layout.  It seems relatively straight forward, but I have not had the AH HA moment yet.

I am not looking for code, I am just looking for input as to whether or not I am looking at this the right way and if not either explain as to why or why not it would work or if there is a better approach to this.

[image: My Real World App Breakdown]
[image: Breakdown Diagram From Site]

Answer (score 0):

You can use already existed widgets to easier making your design. For example [AppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html) for top row and [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) for bottom navigation.

But yes, you can do what you want with all this widgets - also you can use your custom widgets instead of already existed. For example for top row you can use `Row` widget with `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` property.

---

Upd

Firstly full screen should be in Scaffold. Body (between AppBar and BottomNavBar) should be a Column. Space between Image and table Title can be created by Expanded widget with optional sorry text as a child. In that case sorry text will be filled on all available space between image and table with title.

For image you really not necessary to use row - just an image or Container / DecoratedBox with necessary styling and image as child.

For rows from database you can use [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) (maybe it's better to use ListView.builder constructor or separated if you need some separators between rows). Each row should be separated widget for unification. It can be card, but not necessary - you can use a Container or other layouts, more suitable in your case with special required design.

For backend interaction you can use http or dio packages (http is easier for beginners, dio is more functioable).

For waiting indicator you can use smth like CupertinoActivityIndicator (for beginning) or https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit. For loading management there is really cool package - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_easyloading. But you also can use any other widget whatever you're like.

Google maps [here](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)

And I didn't work with PDF yet but this package should be useful - https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

PS all available packages with full information you can find on https://pub.dev - thanks Flutter developers and community.

PPS For state management you can use setState function for beginning, but later it's much better to separate logic and view - by valueNotifiers ([information here](https://suragch.medium.com/flutter-state-management-for-minimalists-4c71a2f2f0c1)), [BLOC](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) or smth else.

And try to make different small widgets instead of one/several bigger ones.

Comment: Can you look at my new attempt / approach to see if I am headed in the right direction?  And after I looked at this before I hit the send button, the 7 rows that are pulled from the database, should they be cards?  There is nothing complicated about my app.  The most complicated things are the Database Calls, Viewing A PDF from a url and keeping it in the app and not needing a 3rd party viewer, loading google maps with data from database, and the final thing in my app, I have my APP ICON spinning while it is downloading the pdf.  Would love to get more feedback and information / resources.

Comment: Hey! Much better) I'll update comment soon